# Opening a new window via my extension

Tags: java, cross-browser, popupwindow, crossrider

I am writing an extension that needs to open a page in a new popup window. However, whenever I try to open a window, the browser's popup blocker prevents the window from opening. I have the following code in my extension.js

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
    var win = window.open("http://google.com", "", "width=200, height=100");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern browser automatically block popups opened by the page. However, you can use the Crossrider [appAPI.openURL](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI-method-openURL) method to opens windows without issue for all supported browsers.

So, using your example, the code would be:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
    appAPI.openURL({
        url: "http://google.com",
        where: "window",
        width: 200,
        height: 100
    });
});
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]